# Is there any way to keep multiple conditions in triggers

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, triggers

I am using `xamarin.forms`. In `xaml` I have wants to use `triggers` like below

```
if(Theme=="Operational" && Selected == true)
//set properties
else if(Theme=="Digital" && Selected == true)
//set properties
```

`Theme` and `Selected` are `binding` properties. Currently I am navigating to different `xaml` pages based on above conditions. I am trying `triggers` like this.

```
<Grid.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger
     Binding="{Binding TabButtons[0].BtnSelected}"
     TargetType="Grid"
     Value="True">
     <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
  </DataTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: You can set multiple triggers inside the `Triggers` tag, one for each state.

Comment: Multi-triggers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#multi-triggers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `MultiTrigger` like this

```
<Grid.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Grid">
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Theme}" Value="OPERATIONAL" />
            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Selected }" Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Grid">
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Theme}" Value="DIGITAL" />
            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
    </MultiTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```